# Combining dataframes with different indices in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've generated a dataframe of probabilities from a scikit-learn classifier like this:

```
def preprocess_category_series(series, key):
    if series.dtype != 'category':
        return series
    if series.cat.ordered:
        s = pd.Series(series.cat.codes, name=key)
        mode = s.mode()[0]
        s[s<0] = mode
        return s
    else:
        return pd.get_dummies(series, drop_first=True, prefix=key)

data = df[df.year == 2012]
factors = pd.concat([preprocess_category_series(data[k], k) for k in factor_keys], axis=1)
predictions = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(clf.classes_, l)) for l in clf.predict_proba(factors)])
```

I now want to append these probabilities back to my original dataframe. However, the `predictions` dataframe generated above, while preserving the order of items in `data`, has lost `data`'s index. I assumed I'd be able to do

```
pd.concat([data, predictions], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

but this generates an error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I've seen that this comes up sometimes if column names are duplicated, but in this case none are. What is that error about? What's the best way to stitch these dataframes back together.

`data.head()`:

```
                year serial  hwtfinl                       region statefip  \
cpsid                                                                        
20121000000100  2012      1  3796.85  East South Central Division  Alabama   
20121000000100  2012      1  3796.85  East South Central Division  Alabama   
20121000000100  2012      1  3796.85  East South Central Division  Alabama   
20120800000500  2012      6  2814.24  East South Central Division  Alabama   
20120800000600  2012      7  2828.42  East South Central Division  Alabama   

                county  month  pernum          cpsidp     wtsupp   ...    \
cpsid                                                              ...     
20121000000100       0     11       1  20121000000101  3208.1213   ...     
20121000000100       0     11       2  20121000000102  3796.8506   ...     
20121000000100       0     11       3  20121000000103  3386.4305   ...     
20120800000500       0     11       1  20120800000501  2814.2417   ...     
20120800000600    1097     11       1  20120800000601  2828.4193   ...     

                 race        hispan educ           votereg  \
cpsid                                                        
20121000000100  White  Not Hispanic  111             Voted   
20121000000100  White  Not Hispanic  111  Did not register   
20121000000100  White  Not Hispanic  111             Voted   
20120800000500  White  Not Hispanic   92             Voted   
20120800000600  White  Not Hispanic   73  Did not register   

                                         educ_parsed      age4         educ4  \
cpsid                                                                          
20121000000100                     Bachelor's degree       65+  College grad   
20121000000100                     Bachelor's degree       65+  College grad   
20121000000100                     Bachelor's degree  Under 30  College grad   
20120800000500  Associate's degree, academic program     45-64  College grad   
20120800000600     High school diploma or equivalent       65+    HS or less   

                race4 region4  gender  
cpsid                                  
20121000000100  White   South    Male  
20121000000100  White   South  Female  
20121000000100  White   South  Female  
20120800000500  White   South  Female  
20120800000600  White   South  Female
```

`predictions.head()`:

```
          a         b         c         d         e         f
0  0.119534  0.336761  0.188023  0.136651  0.095342  0.123689
1  0.148409  0.346429  0.134852  0.169661  0.087556  0.113093
2  0.389586  0.195802  0.101738  0.085705  0.114612  0.112557
3  0.277783  0.262079  0.180037  0.102030  0.071171  0.106900
4  0.158404  0.396487  0.088064  0.079058  0.171540  0.106447
```

Just for fun, I've tried this specifically with only the head rows:

```
pd.concat([data_2012.iloc[0:5], predictions.iloc[0:5]], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Same error comes up.

Comment: this works perfectly for me. what is your Panda's version?

Comment: I'm on version 0.18.0

Comment: could you please print predictions.head() and data.head() ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 0.18.0 too. This is what I tried and it worked. Is this what you are doing?

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X,Y)
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(X)
data['y']=Y
predictions = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(clf.classes_, l)) for l in clf.predict_proba(X)])
pd.concat([data, predictions], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
0  1  2             3             4
0 -1 -1  1  1.000000e+00  1.522998e-08
1 -2 -1  1  1.000000e+00  3.775135e-11
2 -3 -2  1  1.000000e+00  5.749523e-19
3  1  1  2  1.522998e-08  1.000000e+00
4  2  1  2  3.775135e-11  1.000000e+00
5  3  2  2  5.749523e-19  1.000000e+00
```

Comment: That's almost the same as what I'm doing—the only notable difference is that the classifier was generated from a different dataset.

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect.  You can train your classifier with whatever data you want. Can you add bit more of your code?

Comment: Added more code—that's basically the whole thing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is one relatively straightforward solution:

```
predictions.index = data.index
pd.concat([data, predictions], axis=1)
```

Now it works perfectly. No clue why it wouldn't work the way I originally tried.